# How get hours:minutes

Tags: python, time, formatting

I have a script here (not my own) which calculates the length of a movie in my satreceiver. It displays the length in **minutes:seconds**

I want to have that in **hours:minutes**

What changes do I have to make?

This is the peace of script concerned:

```
if len > 0:
    len = "%d:%02d" % (len / 60, len % 60)
else:
    len = ""

res = [ None ]
```

I already got the hours by dividing by 3600 instead of 60 but can't get the minutes...

Thanks in advance

Peter

Comment: Hi, Peter.  Can you add a tag saying what language you're using, so we don't make mistakes with the answer?  thanks!

Comment: There are 60 minutes in one hour.  So if you know how many minutes there are, simply divide the minutes by 60 and you have how many hours.

Answer (score 20):

You can use timedelta

```
from datetime import timedelta
str(timedelta(minutes=100))[:-3]
# "1:40"
```

Comment: Nice. I would add: `str(timedelta(minutes=100))[:-3]` if you do not want seconds to be shown.

Answer (score 13):

```
hours = secs / 3600
minutes = secs / 60 - hours * 60

len = "%d:%02d" % (hours, minutes)
```

Or, for more recent versions of Python:

```
hours = secs // 3600
minutes = secs // 60 - hours * 60

len = "%d:%02d" % (hours, minutes)
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked! This little problem from a complete Python-noob is solved. Thanks to everybody!

Peter

Answer (score 1):

So len the number of seconds in the movie?  That's a bad name.  Python already uses the word len for something else.  Change it.

```
def display_movie_length(seconds):
    # the // ensures you are using integer division
    # You can also use / in python 2.x
    hours = seconds // 3600   

    # You need to understand how the modulo operator works
    rest_of_seconds = seconds % 3600  

    # I'm sure you can figure out what to do with all those leftover seconds
    minutes = minutes_from_seconds(rest_of_seconds)

    return "%d:%02d" % (hours, minutes)
```

All you need to do is figure out what `minutes\_from\_seconds()` is supposed to look like.  If you're still confused, do a little research on the modulo operator.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice answer to this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291909/202168 (a later duplicate of this question)

However if you are dealing with timezone offsets in a datetime string then you need to also handle negative hours, in which case the zero padding in Martijn's answer does not work

eg it would return `-4:00` instead of `-04:00`

To fix this the code becomes slightly longer, as below:

```
offset_h, offset_m = divmod(offset_minutes, 60)
sign = '-' if offset_h < 0 else '+'
offset_str = '{}{:02d}{:02d}'.format(sign, abs(offset_h), offset_m)
```