# Converting minutes to HH:MM format in Python

Tags: python, time

First of all, I'd like to point out that I'm a beginner with Python.

My problem is that I can't figure out what is the proper way to convert minutes to HH:MM format in Python.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Although a duplicate, Martijn's answer is awesome (more than the duplicate's answer)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
'{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(minutes, 60))
```

Here `divmod()` divides the minutes by 60, returning the number of hours and the remainder, in one.

Demo:

```
>>> minutes = 135
>>> '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(minutes, 60))
'02:15'
```

Comment: Better answer than the duplicates! Also, nice intro to `divmod`