# Converting a column of minutes to hours and minutes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a DataFrame in Pandas with a column called "duration" given in minutes.

I want to get a new column that gives the duration in Hours:Minutes ( `HH:MM` ).

Comment: See the answer to the exact same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291883/converting-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting minutes to HH:MM format in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291883/converting-minutes-to-hhmm-format-in-python)

Comment: @DavidGaertner Yeah the accepted answer there is great.

Comment: I saw that one actually and tried to use it. I guess I was having trouble utilizing that into my column. My df is called df_m and my time is in column titled "duration" (no quotes in actual).

Comment: it says duration string passed even though the column is integer

Comment: post your code that is failing. You could use the existing answer as a method and do `df['your_column_with_minutes'].apply(method).`

Comment: My question was answered below using: pd.to_datetime(df.duration, unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your DataFrame looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [20, 10, 80, 120, 30, 190]})
```

Using [**`pd.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with **`strftime`**:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.duration, unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')

0    00:20
1    00:10
2    01:20
3    02:00
4    00:30
5    03:10
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is what an answer from someone who is familiar with Pandas looks like! :)

Comment: Yes! Exactly. Worked perfectly!!

Comment: Note, it's daily-rounded. i.e.:
print(pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(2880), unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M'))
returns 00:00

Answer (score 9):

I’m not familiar with Pandas, but a general way to do the conversion from minutes to minutes and hours is shown below:

```
total_minutes = 374

# Get hours with floor division
hours = total_minutes // 60

# Get additional minutes with modulus
minutes = total_minutes % 60

# Create time as a string
time_string = "{}:{}".format(hours, minutes)

print(time_string) # Prints '6:14' in this example
```

You can also avoid the intermediate steps using `divmod()`:

```
time_string = "{}:{}".format(*divmod(total_minutes, 60))
```

Here, the `*` allows for `format()` to accept the tuple (containing two integers) returned by `divmod()` as two separate arguments.

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use like this:

```
minutes = 204
print("%02d:%02d" % (divmod(minutes, 60)))
```

This will produce a nicely formatted output of   `03:24`.

Answer (score 2):

If the duration is larger than 24:00 hours,  you can use:

```
df.duration = df.duration.apply(lambda x: '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(*divmod(x, 60)))
```

For instance given a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [20, 10, 80, 120, 30, 190]})
```

After applying the operator we get:

1. 00:20
2. 00:10
3. 01:20
4. 02:00
5. 00:30
6. 03:10
7. 40:40