# How to convert pandas dataframe column consisting of minutes in integer format to HH:MM format?

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
15
30
45
60
75
90
```

How can I convert this input in interger format to HH:MM format

Output

```
00:15
00:30
00:45
01:00
01:15
01:30
```

Comment: What have you tried ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How get hours:minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784952/how-get-hoursminutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]})

In [26]: pd.to_datetime(df.duration, unit='m').dt.strftime('%H:%M')
    ...:
Out[26]:
0    00:15
1    00:30
2    00:45
3    01:00
4    01:15
5    01:30
Name: duration, dtype: object

In [27]:
```